# Finding Laplace Transform of the Derivative of $\sin (at)$

Tags: laplace-transform

I was helping somebody solve the problem. It goes like this:

> What is the Laplace transform of derivative of $\sin (at)$

My work:

Well...to get the derivative of $\sin (at)$, let $u = at$ and $du = a.$ Then recall that $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin u) = \cos(u) du$. So....

$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin u ) = \cos (u) du$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin (at) ) = \cos (at) (a)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\sin (at) ) = a \cos (at) $$

We will get the Laplace transform of $a \cos (at)$.

Recall that the Laplace transform of $\cos (\omega_o t)$ is $\frac{s}{s^2 + \omega_o ^2}$. Then the Laplace transform of $a \cos (at)$ would be:

$$\mathcal L \{ \cos (\omega_o t) \} = \frac{s}{s^2 + \omega_o ^2}$$
$$\mathcal L \{ a \cos (at) \} = a \left( \frac{s}{s^2 + (a)^2} \right)$$
$$\mathcal L \{ a \cos (at) \}  = a \left( \frac{s}{s^2 + a^2} \right)$$

Initially, we conclude that Laplace transform of $a \cos (at)$ is $ \frac{a s}{s^2 + a^2} $.

But I have doubts regading the solution, because the equation above can be re-interpreted as getting the Laplace transform of derivative of  $\sin (a (\omega_o)t)$,  where $\omega_o = 1$. If that's the case, I have to get another derivative of $\sin (a (\omega_o)t)$ where $\omega_o = 1$, which is $a \omega_o  \cos (a \omega_o t)$, where $\omega_o = 1$.

The Laplace transform of $\sin (a (\omega_o)t)$ can be solve by remembering a Laplace transform property called "scale change", where in the time-domain, $f(at) $ (with the restriction a > 0 or a = 0), while in the frequency domain, $\frac{1}{a} F \left( \frac{s}{a}\right)$. With that in mind, the Laplace transform of $a \omega_o  \cos (a \omega_o t)$ would be:

$$\mathcal L \{ a \omega_o  \cos (a \omega_o t) \}  = a \left( \frac{1}{a} \left( \frac{\frac{s}{a}}{(\left( \frac{s}{a}) \right) ^2 + (\left( \frac{\omega_o}{a}) \right)^2} \right) \right)$$

$$ =  \left( \frac{\frac{s}{a}}{\frac{s^2}{a^2} + \frac{\omega_o ^2}{a^2}} \right) $$
$$ = \left( \frac{\frac{s}{a}}{\frac{s^2 + \omega_o ^2}{a^2}} \right) $$
$$ = \frac{as}{s^2 + \omega_o ^2} $$

If $\omega_o = 1$, ultimately, the Laplace transform of $a \omega_o  \cos (a \omega_o t)$ is $\frac{as}{s^2 + 1}$

Put it in another way, the Laplace transform of derivative of $\sin (at)$ is  $\frac{as}{s^2 + 1}$.

I got two different Laplace transforms gotten from a single equation, made from two different train of logic. Which one is correct?

Comment: Does $\mathcal{L}\{af\} = a \mathcal{L}\{f\}$ generally hold?  If not, you used it above.

Comment: Yes, but writing $2\cos(at) = e^{iat}+e^{-iat}$ gives a direct way to compute $\int_0^\infty \cos(at) e^{-st}dt$

Comment: @Randall 1st solution.....doesn't hold.....maybe. The 2nd solution, then Yes.....I don't know which one of two approaches in correct XD

Comment: I see now that the LT respects scaling, so I retract my unhelpful question.

Comment: @Randall The Laplace transform is **linear** $$a_1\mathcal{L}[f_1(t)](s)+a_2\mathcal{L}[f_2(t)](s)=\mathcal{L}[a f_1(t)+a_2f_2(t)](s) $$ for  constants $a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${\cal L}(t \mapsto e^{iat})(s) = {\cal L}(t \mapsto \cos{at})(s)+i{\cal L}(t \mapsto \sin{at})(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-(s-ia)t} dt = {1 \over s-ia}$.

By considering the above with $\pm a$ you can get
${\cal L}(t \mapsto \cos{at})(s) = {s \over s^2+a^2}$,
${\cal L}(t \mapsto \sin{at})(s) = {a \over s^2+a^2}$.

It follows that if $f(t) = \sin at$, then
${\cal L}(f')(s) = a{\cal L}(t \mapsto \cos{at})(s) = {as \over s^2+a^2}$.

Comment: Do you mean my 1st approach is correct? Because we have the same answer using the first approach above. Can you confirm it? Or maybe I got the correct answer using a wrong method.....

Comment: You are correct with your initial conclusion. You made a mistake in the second.